# Cursor pagination for nested fields in mongoDB using ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination, cursor

I am trying to paginate a nested document in a mongoDB collection.

This is a sample of what my data looks like. I added `uid` field whose value is a mongo `ObjectId` with the hope that it's going to point me to the next object in the `itemInfo` array.

```
const item = {
  _id: ObjectID,
  name: 'Test',
  itemInfo : [
    {
      uid: "ObjectID",
      itemData: [{}, {}]
    },
    {
      uid: "ObjectID",
      itemData: [{}, {}]
    },
    {
      uid: "ObjectID",
      itemData: [{}, {}]
    },
    {
      uid: "ObjectID",
      itemData: [{}, {}]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, Running this query below returns the next `root` objects in my database and not the next object in the `itemInfo` array.

```
  const pageSkin = await db
    .find({ "itemInfo.uid": { $gt: new ObjectId("UidFromItemInfoArray") } })
    .limit(pgLimit + 1)
```

How can i achieve my desired solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is a document oriented database, means it operates with documents, not subdocuments.

You can use an aggregation framework to [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `itemInfo` so you will have individual documents with exactly 1 item from `itemInfo` array for each item. Then you can apply your logic on the next stage.

Even though you can, you shouldn't. The document size is limited to 16Mb, and order of items in the array is consistent. It will be more efficient to fetch whole document and paginate subdocuments on application level with simple array operators, e.g. [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) in nodejs.